# How do I display this search bar within Element Display in chrome 94?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Hello Im trying to learn scraping, and I'm following this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaNr6QRFtUA&ab_channel=TheDevWay

but I'm not being able to find/use the Search bar at the bottom whithin Chrome's web inspector, which I think will be essential when doing real projects, thank you!

[image]

Comment: Click anywhere inside the elements tree and press Ctrl-F or Cmd-F.

Comment: It worked! thank you very much!